# MySQL, NFS and symbolic links

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, nfs, symbolic-link

I have been migrating an older server running apache2 + mysql under ubuntu to a new server running debian (wheezy). 
The migration works fine while the databases are storted localy (in our case /srv/mysql), but when i try to move them to our centralized storage running NFS and creating symbolic links to the moved files mysql does not seem to find the databases at all. I get no errors from mysql, it just seems to believe there is no such database.

This is the layout of /srv/mysql (few examples):

```
user@server:/srv/mysql# ls -al
total 135440
drwxr-xr-x 50 mysql mysql      4096 May 22 09:59 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  root       4096 May 22 09:59 ..
drwxrwx---  2 mysql mysql      4096 May 21 20:13 database_dir_1
drwx------  2 mysql mysql      4096 May 21 19:07 database_dir_2
drwxrwx---  2 mysql mysql      4096 May 21 20:15 database_dir_3
drwx------  2 mysql mysql      4096 May 21 20:15 database_dir_4
drwxrwx---  2 mysql mysql      4096 May 21 20:15 database_dir_5
```

How i create symbolic links:

```
mv /srv/mysql/database_dir_1 /mnt/centralstorage/customer1/db/database_dir_1
ln -s /mnt/centralstorage/customer1/db/database_dir_1 /srv/mysql/database_dir_1
ls -al /srv/mysql/
drwxrwx---  1 root root      28 May 21 20:13 database_dir_1 -> /mnt/centralstorage/customer1/db/database_dir_1
```

After this mysql no longer sees database_dir_1, but it is fully browseable from cli.

The mounts for /mnt/centralstorage looks like this:

```
192.168.12.222:/srv/storage/customers on /mnt/centralstorage/ type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.12.222,mountvers=3,mountport=49535,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.12.222)
```

And the export on the central server:

```
/srv/storage 192.168.12.30(rw,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

(all names and such have been changed)

Anyone see any issues with the setup?

With regards,
FrontSlash

Edit1:

After some help from @Fox the problem seems to be the NFS connection.
Does anyone see any issues in the nfs configuration i posted above? If you need more information i will post it.

Edit2:

Did a quick test, exportet a new folder on the NFS server, /srv/temp, with the same settings as the other two exports.

Mounted this on the  sql server with fstab instead of the previous startup-script that ran.

The script simply did a

```
mount $host:$dir $mnt_dir/$mmount
```

Which produced this mount:

```
192.168.12.222:/srv/storage/customers on /mnt/centralstorage/ type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.12.222,mountvers=3,mountport=49535,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.12.222)
```

The fstab mount:

```
192.168.12.222:/srv/temp /mnt/temp nfs rw,sync,hard,intr 0   0
```

Produced this:

```
192.168.12.222:/srv/temp on /mnt/temp type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.12.222,mountvers=3,mountport=49535,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.12.222)
```

And here is the weird part, now moving the database dir to the /mnt/temp folder, and creating a link to this, it works. I will continue exploring.

Edit3:
Solution added as answer, nfs-kernel-server had option --manage-gids in /etc/nfs-kernel-server that affected secondary groups for the mysql user.

Comment: Why don't you point your MySQL server configuration to that directory instead of using symlinks?

Comment: Is there anything in your mysqld log?

Comment: @Sven There are 30 databases, all are stored under different folders on the central storage (/srv/centralstorage/customer1/db/database_dir_1/, /customer2/db/database_dir_2 and so on, which is why every database is symlinked to the folders. The /srv/centralstorage folder has roughly 400 folders, most of them are for apache data, but 30 of them also have databases.

Comment: @Fox All my mysql logs are quite empty, i will try enabling debuging (i guess?) to see if i can get anything

Comment: @Fox The general log shows pretty much nothing
When the database is local:

    150522 11:24:32   967 Connect   database1@localhost on
    967 Init DB   database1

When its symlinked:

150522 11:25:01   968 Connect   database1@localhost on
150522 11:25:02   969 Connect   database1@localhost on

And nothing happens, no errors

Comment: btw. do you have apparmor enabled? Or any other security system like that ...

Comment: @Fox Debian does not come with apparmor by default, i have not installed any extra security systems, pretty standard installation. 
Apparmor does seems to be the top contender when i google, but 99% of them are for ubuntu or selinux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Fox and @Sven, i have now solved the problem.

It was a nfs-kernel-server setting, /etc/defaults/nfs-kernel-server contained the option --manage-gids that breaks the usage of secondary groups. So while the mysql user had the right permissions through a secondary group the permissions on the nfs-server's side were wrong.

Hope someone else with the issue sees this before wasting a good few hours!

With regards, FrontSlash

Answer (score 1):

You don't state what engine are you using, but let me presume it's InnoDB (as it's pretty much standard these days) then in [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html)

> (Using actual symbolic links has never been supported for InnoDB tables.)

and

> The DATA DIRECTORY clause is a supported alternative to using symbolic links, which has always been problematic and was never supported for individual InnoDB tables.

You probably could create the .isl files by hand (but **test** before doing that on live).

And there is one warning that may be of interest:

> Do not put MySQL tables on an NFS-mounted volume. NFS uses a message-passing protocol to write to files, which could cause data inconsistency if network messages are lost or received out of order.

Edit: alrighty then... this was not the correct answer, as it's not InnoDB. But I'll keep it in case someone else gets here looking for InnoDB solution.

There is further [reading](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/symbolic-links.html) on MySQL and symlinks.

Especially interesting might be

> If you are not using symlinks, start mysqld with the `--skip-symbolic-links` option to ensure that no one can use mysqld to drop or rename a file outside of the data directory.

As that could be default on Debian. (I do not know.)

Edit2: Ok a better way of checking:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_symlink';
```

Another reason for not picking up databases from outside the `data-dir` is AppArmor, or similar security measure.

btw. it would be worth testing, if it's related to NFS - if symlinks to a completely different part of local fs (or better different fs at all) works  it's in NFS, if it doesen't, it's in symlinks ...

Comment: Its all MyISAM, the server i migrated from is from 2008.
Also, the old server has been running the same configuration since it was launched, symlinked databases stored on a central NFS server.

Comment: symbolic-links                                    TRUE
Is the output i get, so it seems to be enabled

Comment: | have_symlink  | YES   |

Creating a symlink pointing to a local fs works, so i guess it has to be the NFS, damn

Comment: have you tried reading/writing the symlinked files as user mysql is running under? (not just directories, but the files)

Comment: I am starting to think that is has something to do with access, what would be a good test to see if mysql has r/w access?

Comment: I'd probably backup (and make sure it is backed up) one of the directories and tried  to read/write the files ... but that's me ... i like to live on the edge ...

Comment: See the update i posted in the main post, edit 2. Same NFS share settings, same mount options (as per mount output, atleast), different results.